# Safari Mobile: How do I prevent flash of white on page load?

Tags: ios, html, mobile, safari, fouc

When HTML5 pages load in Safari mobile, there is a split-second flash of white before the content displays. Sort of like the old' "flash of unstyled content (FOUC)" problem, but with a white screen instead... call it a "flash of white (FOW)" problem.

Anyone else seen this? How can I get rid of it? I've tried everything I can think of:

1. Setting the body background color to black, at the top of my first style sheet.
2. Setting the body background color to black, way up in the head, with a separate style tag:

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
       body {background: black }
   </style>
   ```
3. In my desperation, I even resorted to adding (gasp!) an inline style to the  tag:

   ```
   <body style="background: black">
   ```

Nothing seems to work... I get this annoying flash of white every time I load a page.

Any ideas?
Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: I would love to know that answer to this as well.  So far all I have been able to do is pre load the page completely before displaying it.